# Microk8s kubernetes preStop httpGet does not work

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, microk8s

The livenessProbe works, but the lifecycle preStop does not.

My yaml:

```
- image: localhost:32000/worker:2022-08-28-h
  name: worker-container 
  ports:
    - containerPort: 55001
      name:  name-b
  livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /healthz
          port: 8080
        initialDelaySeconds: 60
        periodSeconds: 15
        failureThreshold: 3
        timeoutSeconds: 10
  lifecycle:
    preStop:
      httpGet:
        path: /prestop
        port: 8080
```

The pod:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/prestop', (req, res) => {
    console.log("rx prestop")
    .....
    res.send("prestop passed");
});

app.get('/healthz', (req, res) => {
    console.log("health check rx")
    .....
    res.send("Health check passed");
});
```

When I apply my yaml file, I see the health probe working as expected with logs
"health check rx" and "Health check passed".

When I change the code in "...." to return

```
res.status(500).send('Health check did not pass')
```

I see microk8s kubectl restart my module after 3 failed probes.
I was expecting the restart of the container to trigger lifecycle preStop but it
does not.

Am I correct in assuming a container restart because of failed liveness problems will trigger the preStop event? The documentation I could find is not explicit about this.

```
microk8s kubectl delete -f k8s/production/transcribe-worker.yaml
```

Also does not trigger the preStop event.

So I suspect I do not understand how preStop works.
Maybe a limitation of microk8s?
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you execute microk8s kubectl delete -f k8s/production/transcribe-worker.yaml
--force --grace-period=0 does the event trigger ?

Comment: check the pod lifecycle here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination

Comment: delete does not trigger the prestop, but curl http://10.1.56.55:8080/prestop does. Where the IP I got from k describe pod xxxx

Comment: another weird thing, exec into container and execute "ps x".  PID 1 is /bin/sh -c node .... so this explains why I can't process.once('SIGTERM', function (code) . But I though prestop was a fall back

Comment: https://tasdikrahman.me/2019/04/24/handling-singals-for-applications-in-kubernetes-docker/ explains the weird thing that made catching the sigterm not possible hence why I wanted prestop.